# Why doesn't Perl's Net::FTP upload my file?

Tags: perl, ftp

I am trying to upload multiple files via [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::FTP) and Perl. Has anyone done this as even my basic script below fails?

```
use Net::FTP;
use File::Basename;

my $ftp;
my $host ='56.309.24.2';
my $user ='user';
my $pw   ='pass';

my $file ='097360718843.jpeg';
my $path ='public_html/uploaded/product_images';

chomp($host,$user,$pw,$path, $file);

$ftp=Net::FTP->new($host) or die "could not login";
$ftp->login($user,$pw) or die "could not login";
$ftp->cwd($path) or die "could not cwd $path";
$ftp->ls;
$ftp->put($file) or die "could not put $file";
$ftp->site("chmod 600 " . basename($file));
```

Here's a log of the transfer:

```
Net::FTP>>> 
Net::FTP(2.75) 
Net::FTP>>> Exporter(5.58) 
Net::FTP>>> 
Net::Cmd(2.26) 
Net::FTP>>> IO::Socket::INET(1.27) 
Net::FTP>>> IO::Socket(1.28) 
Net::FTP>>> IO::Handle(1.24) 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [TLS] ---------- 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed. 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-Local time is now 16:19. Server port: 21. 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server. 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> user user_name 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 331 User user_name OK. Password required 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PASS .... 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 230-User user_name has group access to: user_name wheel 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is / 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> CWD public_html/uploaded/product_images/ 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/uploaded/product_images 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PORT 192,168,1,10,200,38 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 PORT command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> NLST 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 150 Connecting to port 50703 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226-Options: -a 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226 Output truncated to 2000 matches 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> ALLO 7903 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 Zzz... 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PORT 192,168,1,10,200,39 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 PORT command successful 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> STOR 097360718843.jpeg 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 150 Connecting to port 50704 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226-File successfully transferred
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226 0.381 seconds (measured here), 20.21 Kbytes per second 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> SITE chmod 600 097360718843.jpeg 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 Permissions changed on 097360718843.jpeg
```

Comment: where does the script fail?  Or does the script complete but just not upload the file?

Comment: It completed but does not upload the file.

Comment: How are you checking that the file has been uploaded? According to the debug log you posted, it was uploaded fine.

Comment: What does the FTP server log say?

Comment: The `226-File successfully transferred` means your file was uploaded. If its not present on the server, (a) you uploaded it somewhere other than where you expected; try find, (b) you uploaded it to the wrong server; (c) your FTP server is borked.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 1) 
    or die "Could not create FTP object: $@";
```

Additional good practice:

- Make sure you have

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  ```
- Don't declare variables before they are needed.
- Include the error in the error messages.

In short, try the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::FTP;

my $host ='56.309.24.2';
my $user ='user';
my $pw   ='pass';

my $file ='097360718843.jpeg';
my $path ='public_html/uploaded/product_images';

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 1) 
    or die "Could not connect to '$host': $@";

$ftp->login($user, $pw) 
    or die sprintf "Could not login: %s", $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd($path) 
    or die sprintf "Could not login: %s", $ftp->message;

$ftp->ls;

$ftp->binary;

$ftp->put($file) 
    or die die sprintf "Could not login: %s", $ftp->message;

$ftp->site("chmod 600 $file");
```

Comment: Ok I got some output. Im logged into the server so the connection is made but no upload.

Comment: Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.75)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.58)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.26)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.27)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.28)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.24)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [TLS] ----------
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-Local time is now 16:19. Server port: 21.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c6a8)<<< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Try `$ftp->binary` so you are not trying to upload a binary file in ASCII mode. Also, are you running the exact script above or have you made any modifications? Do you really get no more debug messages?

Comment: sorry here is the full output

Comment: sorry wont allow me to add it all in one comment so Im breaking it up into two

Comment: Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.75)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.58)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.26)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.27)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.28)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.24)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [TLS] ----------
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 220-Local time is now 16:35. Server port: 21.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> user user_name
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 331 User user_name OK. Password required
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 230-User user_name has group access to:  user_name   wheel   
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> CWD public_html/uploaded/product_images/
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/uploaded/product_images
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PORT 192,168,1,10,200,38
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 PORT command successful

Comment: Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> NLST
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 150 Connecting to port 50703
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226-Options: -a 
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226 Output truncated to 2000 matches
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> ALLO 7903
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 Zzz...
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> PORT 192,168,1,10,200,39
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 PORT command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> STOR 097360718843.jpeg
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 150 Connecting to port 50704
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226-File successfully transferred

Comment: Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 226 0.381 seconds (measured here), 20.21 Kbytes per second
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)>>> SITE chmod 600 097360718843.jpeg
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x180c648)<<< 200 Permissions changed on 097360718843.jpeg

Comment: so, it looks the file transfer is happening. Is it possible that it's being written somewhere unexpected? I would also recommend removing that last command just to make sure it's not having any unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Well, its not actually uploading the file as I cannot see it in the dir. I can create files in this dir and have uploaded files into it too, with a 3rd party ftp program. Im really at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: A lot of these comments should be part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the protection on the destination directory.
Make sure you can create files there.

Check the protection on the files themselves
Make sure you can overwrite them.

Comment: Well, its not actually uploading the file as I cannot see it in the dir. I can create files in this dir and have uploaded files into it too, with a 3rd party ftp program. Im really at a loss as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The upload is successful:

```
226-File successfully transferred
```

and it should be accessible via file url in a web browser. Yet you cannot see it in a ftp client because of ftp server file listing limit - the file quantity exceeds 2000:

```
226 Output truncated to 2000 matches
```

The solution would be saving to other folder or if you have access to server-side ftp config changing that file limit.